# which() Function in SystemML

Tags: systemml

I’m a developer want to use SystemMl for running R-Code from our business people on a Spark cluster.

I’ve studied http://apache.github.io/systemml/dml-language-reference , however, haven’t found a implementation of the R function “which” or any alternative functionality. Has anyone an idea how I could

## Given

v = c(1,4,NA,2, 5, NA)

## Expect indexes where value meets condition =  int[] 2 5

v2 = which(v>2)

## Expect indexes where is.na returns TRUE =   int[] 3 6

v3 = which(is.na(v))

I’ve already considered the functions replace() and removeEmpty(), but they don’t exactly meets my needs.

Thanks a lot in advance
Kuno

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbles over the same problem. R's `which` can be emulated with the following workaround:

```
v2 = removeEmpty(target=seq(1,length(v)) * (v>2), margin="rows")
```

Furthermore, SystemML does not allow `NA`, so you would need to replace it with 0 or `NaN` (e.g., `0/0=NaN`). The extraction would then look like `(v==0)` or `(v!=v)`, where the latter accounts for the fact that any comparison with a `NaN` is false and so `NaN` is the only value that is not equal to itself.